# Is there a formal idiom that means "fed up with something"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there a formal idiom that means "*fed up with something*"?

I am wondering if there's a formal idiom, because the expression is an informal expression. After doing some research, I found "be sick and tired of", but it's not formal.

> I am fed up with these protests. I have been putting up with these loudmouths who have no respect for the law.

Comment: Idioms are, by definition, usually informal.  I think what you're looking for is a non-idiomatic, straightforward phrasing like, "I have lost all patience with these protests."

Comment: I agree with Canadian Yankee. @pasanav, do you really mean a “formal” idiom? If so, what exactly is that?

Answer (score 3):

[have had enough](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+had+enough):

to have had as much of something as is needed or will be tolerated.

If you say that you [have had enough](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/have-had-enough), you mean that you are unhappy with a situation and you want it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom **"I've had it up to here!"** comes to mind. People usually point to the neck or head area while saying it.
Meaning suffering that's getting quite unbearable.

Comment: -1 This is synonymous but, if anything, even **less** formal than "fed up with".  pasanav specifically asked for a "formal" idiom.